# Unable to create WebApp in Azure

Tags: azure

I am unable to create Web APP because of the below error regarding the subscription even though I am the Global Admin on the tenant :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SCOT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global Admin is an Azure AD permission, has nothing to do with the subscription. You need someone with owner rights on the subscription to grant you access to register resource providers.

Comment: Apologies I forgot to mention that I am the owner over the Subscription as well in the issue but still got the error. I followed your advice and checked articles regarding registering part and now I don't see the error. Thank you for your help on this :)